# Вызов функции через строковый литерал

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo() {
    var _privatFoo = function(String callback, args) {
        //вызов функции по имени переменной: ("_foo" + callback)(args), например, _fooName1(args);
    }
    var _fooName1 = function(args) {
        //do smth...
        return args;
    }
    var _fooName2 = function(args) {
        //do smth...
        return args;
    }
}
```

Как я могу вызвать приватные функции, присвоенные локальным переменным функции с передачей аргументов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Foo() {
    var _privatFoo = function(callbackName, args) {
        if (functionHolder[callbackName])
            functionHolder[callbackName](args); // например, Name1(args);
    }
    var functionHolder = {
      Name1: function(args) {
        //do smth...
        return args;
      },
      Name2: function(args) {
        //do smth...
        return args;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все правильно, я не сразу на область видимости посмотрел, единственное, лишний контейнер, но его никак, видимо не обойти

Comment: @Alaksander, `eval` поможет обойти

Comment: Изначально не рассматриваю, дабы не нарушать принятый стандарт кода